# Change property (msi) in managed bootstrapper (wpf)?

Tags: c#, wix, bootstrapper

A have a WPF Setup Application. I Have TextBox that binds to a Property `ProductCode` in my ViewModel.

How can I make the packages to be set "`DEF`" property in .msi project?

My code:

WPF:

```
 private void InstallExecute()
        {
            InstallEnabled = false;
            Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["ABC"] = "zyx";
            MainWindowViewModel.PlanAction(LaunchAction.Install);
        }
```

Bootstrapper:

```
<Variable Name="ABC" bal:Overridable="yes" />

<MsiProperty Name="DEF" Value="[ABC]"/>
```

.MSI:

```
 <Property Id="DEF" />
```

Project with Action:

```
var test = session["DEF"].ToString(); //always gives empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the MsiProperty like this inside your bundle:

```
<MsiPackage Id='MyApp' Description='My Application' SourceFile="$(var.SetupMyApp.TargetPath)">
  <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[MyAppInstallLocation]"/>
</MsiPackage>
```

Add a burn variable for it, also in the bundle:

```
<Variable bal:Overridable="yes" Name="MyAppInstallLocation" Value=""/>
```

And then

```
Bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["MyAppInstallLocation"] = "C:\MyApp";
```

somewhere in your bootstrapper, obviously before you start the install.